# Error installing gcc 7 on a MacBook

Tags: terminal, homebrew, gcc

I have Mac OS 11.2.3 (the new MacBook Air) I am trying to install gcc version 7 using the command:

brew install gcc@7

However, I get the following error:

gcc@7: The x86_64 architecture is required for this software.
Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.

What does this mean? How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Why do you need such an old version as gcc 7?

Comment: It seems that the program I am trying to install (p4vasp) requires an old version for gcc 7. I honestly don't know much about these things. I do not even know what the current version of gcc is

Comment: The message means that the only supported architecture for the formula is X86_64.  Not ARM64.  You could I suppose try to force a build from source, but where are you getting the gcc7 requirement anyway?  The Github repository references macOS 10.13 and has macOS compilation instructions.

Comment: The gcc7 is hardcoded in a makefile. It is also python 2 and I would expect to need the same compiler as python2 was built with. So using insecure software. The build system is not good  I expect you could replace all the gcc-7 with gcc (I would first try clang++)

Comment: Also look at [issue](https://github.com/orest-d/p4vasp/issues/21) Also look at the forks in insights, the last 2 forks seem to have commits for macOS. (But the project is not maintained I would use another tool or completely review it)